# $R\mbox{ is a right multiplier and }R(a)b=a\overset{?}{\implies} A\mbox{ is unital }$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and $R:A\to A$ its right multilplier. Is it true that
$$
\exists b\in A\quad \forall a\in A \quad R(a)b=a\qquad
$$
implies $A$ is unital. I know this is true if A is a weak$^*$ dense ideal of $W^*$-algebra. But what about the general case?

This question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178276/r-mbox-is-a-right-multiplier-and-rab-a-overset-implies-a-mbox-is-unit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is positively answered on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178276/r-is-a-right-multiplier-and-rab-a-overset-implies-a-is-unital/178514#178514).

Even more is true. If $A$ have right divisor of all its elements, then $A$ is unital.